# Polars: inefficiency of over expression

Tags: python, python-polars

I found out that at least for the scenario below, doing `over` is much slower (2~3x) than doing `groupby/agg` + `explode`. And, the results are exactly the same.

Based on this finding, I have the following questions:

- Is such behaviour as expected? If so, should we always do a 2-step procedure (`groupby/agg` + `explode`) instead of using `over` directly?
- Or, does this mean that there may be some room to optimize `over`?
- Or, the performance between these two approaches really depends on the problem setup and users should try to see which approach fits the better?

```
import time

import numpy as np
import polars as pl
from polars.testing import assert_frame_equal

## setup
rng = np.random.default_rng(1)

nrows = 20_000_000
df = pl.DataFrame(
    dict(
        id=rng.integers(1, 50, nrows),
        id2=rng.integers(1, 500, nrows),
        v=rng.normal(0, 1, nrows),
        v1=rng.normal(0, 1, nrows),
        v2=rng.normal(0, 1, nrows),
        v3=rng.normal(0, 1, nrows),
        v4=rng.normal(0, 1, nrows),
        v5=rng.normal(0, 1, nrows),
        v6=rng.normal(0, 1, nrows),
        v7=rng.normal(0, 1, nrows),
        v8=rng.normal(0, 1, nrows),
        v9=rng.normal(0, 1, nrows),
        v10=rng.normal(0, 1, nrows),
    )
)

## over
start = time.perf_counter()
res = (
    df.lazy()
    .select(
        [
            "id",
            "id2",
            *[
                (pl.col(f"v{i}") - pl.col(f"v{i}").mean().over(["id", "id2"]))
                / pl.col(f"v{i}").std().over(["id", "id2"])
                for i in range(1, 11)
            ],
        ]
    )
    .collect()
)
time.perf_counter() - start
# 8.541702497983351

## groupby/agg + explode
start = time.perf_counter()
res2 = (
    df.lazy()
    .groupby(["id", "id2"])
    .agg(
        [
            (pl.col(f"v{i}") - pl.col(f"v{i}").mean()) / pl.col(f"v{i}").std()
            for i in range(1, 11)
        ],
    )
    .explode(pl.exclude(["id", "id2"]))
    .collect()
)
time.perf_counter() - start
# 3.1841439900454134

## compare results
assert_frame_equal(res.sort(["id", "id2"]), res2.sort(["id", "id2"])[res.columns])
```